# Escaping correctly creating an alias

Tags: bash, alias

```
alias wp='watch -d --interval 1 "oc get pods | grep 0/1 | grep -v Completed | awk {'print \$1,\$2,\$3,\$4'} | column -t "'
```

I'm trying to escape this command.
I've tried escaping the print quotes with \ but no success. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a tricky one. The problem is that you can't have internal `'`, that exits the alias definition. So you need `"` for the `awk` command. Next, you need one level of escaping for each thing that can "consume" a `$` sign. Here, you need one escape for the `"` of the awk, another for the `"` in the command you give to `watch` and a third for the shell itself. This should work:

```
alias wp='watch -d --interval 1 "oc get pods | grep 0/1 | grep -v Completed | awk \"{print \\\$1,\\\$2,\\\$3,\\\$4}\" | column -t"'
```

If I were you, I would use a function instead of an alias which allows for a slightly simplified syntax:

```
wp(){
    command1='oc get pods | grep 0/1 | grep -v Completed'
    command2='awk "{print \$1,\$2,\$3,\$4}" | column -t'

    watch -d --interval 1 "$command1 | $command2"
}
```

Finally, note that you don't need `grep` if you're already using `awk`:

```
 wp(){
  command="oc get pods | awk '/0\/1/ && !/Completed/{print \$1,\$2,\$3,\$4}' | column -t"
  watch -d --interval 1 "$command"
}
```